# Time difference, php, mysql, ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am posting variables from ajax form to php server side using $_POST
I have two variables, time and amount. In the server, I have a MYSQL database that has _end_time (data type: time) and amount (data type: currency)
The amount is working well on the sql select 
however, I am unable to compare $_POST time which is this format ('10:05:00') and _end_time also in the same format in the database
I want to find where the difference between post time and mysql time is less than 3 minutes

here is my select statement

```
SELECT end_date,_money From Sales 
Where    DATE(`end_date`)=date(now()+interval 8 hour) 
AND money =".$amountSold." 
AND (TIMEDIFF('".$timeSold."', 'end_time')/60) <3 
ORDER BY `end_date` DESC
```

no data is posted back
I have also tried

`(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Sales.end_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('".$timeSold."'))/60<3`

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quote instead of backtick quote in the `end_time` field. That may be the reason.